# Rails 3 create model with temporary argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model that needs to rename a file when being created. In order to keep my controller skinny, this is done in the `after_validation` method of my model. I don't want this argument stored in the DB, I just need to access it in the `after_validation` model.

The problem is that when from my controller I call `Model.create(:my_temp_arg => "blahh")` I get the `Can't mass-assign protected attributes` error.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to `attr_accessible` list and attr_accessor:

```
attr_accessor :my_temp_arg
attr_accessible :other fields, :my_temp_arg
```

Comment: I tried, but if I do that I just get the `unknown attribute` error

Comment: I was assuming that you already added attr_accessor, you will need to add it as well, I will add to answer.